# "LinearLayout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless" warning

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout

```
...
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:baselineAligned="false">
            <include layout="@layout/sublayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            <include layout="@layout/sublayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
...
```

and I don't understand why I get the warning "This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless".

What I'm trying to do with my layout design is to center both sublayaout1 and sublayaout2 in the middle of the screen. In order to do that I need the android:layout_centerInParent attribute to be true and I need the RelativeLayout parent as a container since it is inside an horizontal LinearLayout with multiple rows.

Is there any way to center the the LinearLayout without the RelativeLayout?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` on the `LinearLayout`. Remove the unnecessary `RelativeLayout`. Not to be confused with `android:layout_gravity`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <include layout="@layout/sublayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <include layout="@layout/sublayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did it but the result is not the same

Comment: Note that the difference is that the RelativeLayout has a width of the entire width of the screen and the LinearLayout has a width of 320dp, which is less than the width of the screen. Also note that the LinearLayout is centered with respect to the RelativeLayout. If I remove the RelativeLayout and use android:gravity="center", it will not have any effect since the width is fixed to 320dp (not to the width of the screen).

Comment: Use both `android:gravity="center"` which will center children of the `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="center"` (or relative layout equivalent) to center the `LinearLayout` in its parent. Does that work?

Comment: It worked! However it fires another warning "Nested weights are bad for perfomance"

Comment: Is the parent of this linear layout another horizontal linear layout?

Comment: No it's not. The parent is a vertical linearlayout

Comment: There will probably be no easy way around that. I believe you can safely ignore this warning.